# The link/URL vanishes when pdfrw is used in conjunction with ReportLab

Tags: reportlab, pdfrw

Trying to some add contents to PDF file using pdfrw and ReportLab. If I use PDF file with text having hyperlink, the link just disapperes from the document.

[Link to pdf File.](https://github.com/pmaupin/pdfrw/files/11403797/link_file.pdf)

```
# split_with_rl.py

from pdfrw import PdfReader
from pdfrw.buildxobj import pagexobj
from pdfrw.toreportlab import makerl

from reportlab.pdfgen.canvas import Canvas

def split(path, number_of_pages, output):
    pdf_obj = PdfReader(path)

    my_canvas = Canvas(output)

    # create page objects
    pages = pdf_obj.pages[0: number_of_pages]
    pages = [pagexobj(page) for page in pages]

    for page in pages:
        my_canvas.setPageSize((page.BBox[2], page.BBox[3]))
        my_canvas.doForm(makerl(my_canvas, page))
        my_canvas.showPage()

    # write the new PDF to disk
    my_canvas.save()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    split('file_with_link.pdf', 10, 'output.pdf')
```